# coretext space between lines in multiline

Tags: ios, uitextview, multiline, uifont, core-text

UITextView and Core Text drawing

why spacing different between multiline?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easy

```
CGFloat lineHeight = 17.0;

CTParagraphStyleSetting settings[2] = {
        { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMinimumLineHeight, sizeof(lineHeight), &lineHeight },
        { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMaximumLineHeight, sizeof(lineHeight), &lineHeight }
}
```